# Facebook SDK 3.2 login only works if app does not terminate

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, sdk

My Facebook login only works if it does not exit the app in order to login. For example, it only works if the app logs in with iOS6 native dialog or with a forced web view. When I try to log in using safari or the Facebook app, it will show me a page that says I have already authorized the app. I click "OK" and it takes me back into my app, but the login did not complete.

Any ideas? I have been stuck on this for a long time...

Thanks in advance!

Below is the code I use to log in. If I force a web view, the login will work since it does not have to switch out of the application to log in, but doing this every time for the user does not seem to be very efficient.

```
 FBSession *session =
[[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:@"12345"
                     permissions:nil
                 urlSchemeSuffix:@"paid"
              tokenCacheStrategy:nil];

if (allowLoginUI ||
    (session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)) {
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
    [session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView
            completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
    result = session.isOpen;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: @FabioCardoso I added my login code above

Comment: Basically, the completion handler is never called when I return back to my app

Comment: Try it without the `allowLoginUI`on the IF statement.

Comment: @FabioCardoso It doesn't do anything without `allowLoginUI`. It seems to log in if I set "Application does not run in background" to NO. So if the app is multitasking, it'll work, but I want it to work without having to turn multitasking on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented `- application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` in your app delegate, declared app support for the URL scheme `fb[YOUR APP ID]` and wired things up so that the app delegate call-in eventually gets to `[[FBSession activeSession] handleOpenURL:url]`?

The way the external web view works is that if login is successful then it attempts to open a URL with the app-specific scheme that includes the login token. You're supposed to have set your app up as the handler for the URL scheme and then to pass the relevant URL into the Facebook SDK so that it can decode the token.

Comment: Yes, I did an NSLog on the URL when it opens the app again and it returns an access_Token.

Comment: What's the return result of `handleOpenURL:`? Does `[FBSession activeSession]` definitely return non-`nil`?

Comment: `handleOpenURL` returns fb[app_id]://authorize/#access_token=[access_token] and `activeSession` is non-nil

Comment: It seems to log in if I set "Application does not run in background" to NO. So if the app is multitasking, it'll work, but I want it to work without having to turn multitasking on.

Comment: `handleOpenURL` is defined to return a `BOOL` — see line 425 of FBSession.h. Are you sure you're using the right entry point?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake — it's line 522 nowadays. See https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBSession.h

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add the following method in your AppDelegate implementation file? (Assuming you don't have it already):

```c
//
// During the Login with FB flow, the app passes control to the Facebook iOS app or Facebook in mobile Safari.
// After the user is authenticated, the app will be called back with the session information.
// This method calls the Facebook session object that handles the incoming URL.
//
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *) sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm already calling handleOpenURL I did an NSLog of the URL and it returns the app id and access_token.